# JavaFX Bidirectional binding text to Doubleproperty negative numbers

Tags: java, parsing, javafx

I want to bind my input field to my variable which is DoubleProperty.
It works except when I want to write a negative number. After I start with "-" I get a ParseException.

Is there a way how I could handle it.

```
inputLat.textProperty().bindBidirectional(pm.latProperty(), new NumberStringConverter("#######.##"));
```

Error

```
Juni 23, 2021 1:29:17 PM com.sun.javafx.binding.BidirectionalBinding$StringConversionBidirectionalBinding changed
WARNUNG: Exception while parsing String in bidirectional binding
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "-"
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "-"
    at java.base/java.text.NumberFormat.parse(NumberFormat.java:434)
    at javafx.util.converter.NumberStringConverter.fromString(NumberStringConverter.java:94)
    ... 52 more
```

Comment: @PalLaden added the error message

Comment: See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html).

Comment: Are you sure `inputLat.textProperty().bindBidirectional(pm.latProperty(), new NumberStringConverter("#######.##"));` is giving you the exception?

Comment: @PalLaden yes updated the Error as you see in the last row

Comment: There is no `-` in the line you have provided.

Comment: The "-" is the input in the TextField and you see that it caused the error in the third line

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: 1. This isn't an error, it's a warning. 2. It's also not unexpected: the bidirectional binding will update `latProperty` any time the text changes. If you want that to happen, you need to decide what value you want `latProperty` to take if the text represents a partially-entered value (such as `"-"` or an empty string), and code that logic into the `StringConverter`. 3. A better approach might be to set a `TextFormatter` on the text field and bind to the formatter's `valueProperty`, which changes only when the text is committed.